# Allow users to add own taxonomy terms to uploaded images

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, media

I am using [imagepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagepicker) moudule to allow users to add images to the website.

I want them to have a 'tags' bar where they can add words that describe the image they have uploaded (so that other users can also search by those tags)
One like the one on this site when you upload a question!

[image]

Comment: are you try with hierarchical select module??